# Desktop machine doesnt power on until it has power from wall for around a minute

Tags: power

I have an old Windows XP machine from 2004 that doesn't power on until it has time to "warm up" after its plugged into the wall. If I try to press the power button after I've plugged it in it doesn't show any life. Motherboard seems healthy with no leaking caps. Wondering if I should be checking internal power supply for bad caps. Is this something I should be worried about or is it normal behavior?

Comment: Most likely a dead CMOS battery. Can you please edit your question to add more details like what is the exact make and model of the machine? And how long has it been since it has been last powered on? Recently or closer to 2004?

Comment: But very likely capacitors as well. They don't have to be bulging or leaking to be out of specs.

Comment: The power supply has not been turned on for I would say around 9 - 10 years or so, maybe more but can't remember last time it was turned on so it is very cold. The computer used to have a different power supply but one day blew. I presume from being left on too long (48 hours). That's when I swapped the power supply to the one in question.